# Alamofire causes crash on iPhone 5

Tags: swift, alamofire

I currently give some users access to my app via TestFlight so that they can test it. On every iPhone the App works perfectly without any problems but on the iPhone 5 the app crashes every time. In the xCode simulator everything works properly but not on a real device.

It looks like Alamofire causes the crash. The problem is in Alamofire>Source>Features>ResponseSerialization.swift>response(queue:completionHandler:)

Here is the code from the function:

```
/// Adds a handler to be called once the request has finished.
///
/// - parameter queue:             The queue on which the completion handler is dispatched.
/// - parameter completionHandler: The code to be executed once the request has finished.
///
/// - returns: The request.
@discardableResult
public func response(queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, completionHandler: @escaping (DefaultDataResponse) -> Void) -> Self {
    delegate.queue.addOperation {
        (queue ?? DispatchQueue.main).async {
            var dataResponse = DefaultDataResponse(
                request: self.request,
                response: self.response,
                data: self.delegate.data,
                error: self.delegate.error
            )

            dataResponse.add(self.delegate.metrics)

            completionHandler(dataResponse)
        }
    }

    return self
}
```

`completionHandler(dataResponse)` looks like it is the problem.

Below there is also a screenshot from xCode

[image]

Is this a Alamofire related problem? Because on every other device (5s, 6 Plus, 7 Plus, SE and 7) it works without any problems. The crash occur when the iPhone is connected to WiFi and when it uses the mobile network.

Thanks for any tips!

EDIT:
This should be the code section that is called when starting the application:

```
Alamofire.request("https://app.site.tld/mobile/ios", parameters: parameters).response { response in
        print("Request: \(response.request)")
        print("Response: \(response.response)")
        print("Error: \(response.data)")

        if response.response != nil{
            if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Data: \(utf8Text)")

                let weatherDataArr = utf8Text.components(separatedBy: "~")
                guard let hash = String(weatherDataArr[0]) else {
                    completion(nil)
                    return
                }
                do {
                    //working with received data.
                    //let currData: wData = try wData(hash: hash, ....)

                    completion(currData)
                } catch {
                    print("error creating Object: \(error)")
                    completion(nil)
                }

            }
            else {
                completion(nil)
            }
        }else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
```

Just found a warning in xCode that says:

> 'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block

Comment: What iOS version does this iPhone 5 have? And what iOS versions are on other devices?

Comment: Is there any error message or code?

Comment: Where are you calling the function. It seems like it is unowned. Is it from a static instance called without a reference?

Comment: To me it looks like there are subsequent frames in that thread. What does the handler look like?

Comment: @mixel: the iPhone 5 was running iOS 10.1.1 and is now in iOS 10.2. The other iPhone have installed iOS 10.0.1, 10.1, 10.2 and 10.2.1 Beta.

Comment: @Emptyless it's not a static function, but the functions gets called when the app starts and then it immediately crashes on the iPhone 5 but not in the other iPhones.

Comment: @Andreas I've added the code in my question

Comment: My answer might not be relevant since it seems to be a problem with the single phone that runs a 32 bit architecture, but otoh you might be doing some architecture dependent stuff in your handler, like `arc4random`

Comment: @Andreas I would not say that it is a 32bit problem because one tester tests the app on an iPhone 5C which is also 32bit..

Answer (score 0):

First simplify to remove clutter

```
Alamofire.request("https://app.site.tld/mobile/ios", parameters: parameters).response { response in
    print("Request: \(response.request)")
    print("Response: \(response.response)")
    print("Error: \(response.data)")

    var result: wData? = nil
    defer { completion(result) }

    guard response.response != nil else { return }

    if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("Data: \(utf8Text)")

        let weatherDataArr = utf8Text.components(separatedBy: "~")

        guard let hash = String(weatherDataArr[0]) else { return }

        //working with received data.
        //let currData: wData = try wData(hash: hash, ....)

        result = currData
    }
}
```

Then we can ask ourselves

1. How are you 100% sure there are elements in `weatherDataArr`? If not, use `guard let hash = weatherDataArr.first else { return }`
2. What happens under `//working with received data.`?

Comment: Your code causes the following error: `Cannot call value of non-function type 'HTTPURLResponse?'`

1. Yes I'm 100% sure that there is data, this is all done on the server side.
2. Im just splitting the array and set some values that I need.

BTW: the whole code block is in a function: `func getWeatherData(stnID: String, completion: @escaping (wData?) -> Void) {`

Comment: My bad. I wrote `completionHandler` instead of `completion`. 1. Ok (I thought you said you ran this code on *phones*, not on server?) 2. Simplify the function while preserving the bug, and post it http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: even after changing it from `completionHandler` to `completion` only it still shows me the same error. 1) Yeah thats right, this code runs on the phone but is only executed if the user have an active internet connection and the server response definitely with values..

Comment: "Only executed if the server responds definitely with values" — well that's not apparent from the code you've provided. Make a minimal example and post all relevant code.